# Making Anagrams : Temp Anagram length subtraction method

Tags: python, anagram

Question : Given two strings that may or may not be of the same length, determine the minimum number of character deletions required to make them anagrams. Any characters can be deleted from either of the strings.

My method :

```
def anagramlength(string1,string2):
    temp = []
    if len(string1)> len(string2):
        x= string2
        y=string1
    else:
        x = string1
        y=string2
    for c in x:
        if c in y:
            temp.append(c)
        else:
            continue
    return (len(x)- len(temp)) + len(y)- len(temp)
```

Using the test case:

```
anagramlength('bugexikjevtubidpulaelsbcqlupwetzyzdvjphn','la‌​joipfecfinxjspxmevqx‌​uqyalhrsxcvgsdxxkacs‌​pbchrbvvwnvsdtsrdk')
```

I'm getting `28`, while the correct answer is `40`. Can you help me find where my program is going wrong?

Comment: What is your question?  All this code does is to define a function; there's no reproducible problem here.

Comment: And what is the output from your attempt?

Comment: Made changes to the ques. Please read again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm can be reduced to linear time by using a dictionary to store the letters of each string.

```
def anagramlength(string1,string2):
    difference = {}


    for letter in string1:
        if letter not in difference:
            difference[letter] = 0
        difference[letter] += 1

    for letter in string2:
        if letter not in difference:
            difference[letter] = 0
        difference[letter] -= 1

    return sum(abs(n) for n in difference.values())
```

Comment: I used the test case :

anagramlength('bugexikjevtubidpulaelsbcqlupwetzyzdvjphn','lajoipfecfinxjspxmevqxuqyalhrsxcvgsdxxkacspbchrbvvwnvsdtsrdk')


I'm getting 28 while your logic is getting 40.
Can you help me find where my program is going wrong?

Comment: You do not check for repeated string. e,g, 'a' and 'aaaaaa' should return 5, but returns 0.

Comment: I just ran it my function returned 5, so it does take care of repetition. I guess the problem is something else.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, bad example, it is still a problem checking repetitions on line 10. Try 'aab','bba'.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified by using a dictionary to store characters.

```
def anagramlength(str1,str2):
    dict = {}


    for char in str1:
        if char not in dict:
            dict[char] = 0
        dict[char] += 1

    for char in str2:
        if char not in dict:
            dict[char] = 0
        dict[char] -= 1

return sum(abs(n) for n in dict.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

This another simplified solution without using a dictionary:

```
a = input().strip()
b = input().strip()

def number_needed(a, b):
    n=0
    for i in a:
        if i not in b or a.count(i)> b.count(i):
            n += 1
            a=a.replace(i, '', 1)
    for j in b:
        if j not in a or b.count(j) > a.count(j):
            n +=1
            b=b.replace(j, '', 1)
    return n

print(number_needed(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Code :

```
def anagramlength(string1,string2):
    temp = []
    if len(string1)> len(string2):
        x= string2
        y=string1
    else:
        x = string1
        y=string2
    lenb=len(y)
    for c in x:
        if c in y:
            temp.append(c)
            y = list(y)
            y[y.index(c)]= None
    return (len(x)- len(temp)) + lenb - len(temp)
```